# Naming Conventions for Variables

Tags: java, naming, convention

I have four variable in a program: xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel

Each one of them should have a setter/getter, but it will be awkward to say:

```
setXpos()
getXpos()
getXvel()
setXvel()
```

Is there a naming convention for these variables that is short and efficient?

Comment: That's about it, but I might recommend writing a vector class and passing those around instead of dealing with xp, yp, xv, yv, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've listed in your code snippet *is* the naming convention.

The more important question is, how can they be reframed for readability? As someone who hasn't seen your program, the four functions you listed seem perfectly clear to me. I'm having a hard time coming up with something clearer.

Any time you abandon a convention, even if the convention makes things icky, you lose readability/clarity (as people expect those conventions to be fulfilled). You have to weigh the advantage of abandoning an icky convention-result for something better against that loss of abandoning the convention.

All this to say, you have my permission to use 'getXvel()'. Godspeed. =)

Answer (score 2):

How about `getXPos()` and `getXVel()`? Although, `getXPosition()` and `getXVelocity()` seems clearer. It depends on context, but it took me a second to figure out that you didn't mean `val`.

---

This goes beyond your question, but (under the right circumstances) I might argue doing this:

```
foo.getX().position();
foo.getX().velocity();
```

Comment: You create a class that has `position()` and `velocity()` methods, and return an instance of that class when invoking `getX()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few schools of thought on naming convention. If you follow java bean conventions then your setters and getters are correct, however I would consider renaming your variables to be more descriptive, i.e. `horizontalPosition`, `verticalPosition`, `verticalVelocity`, `horizontalVelocity` with the getters and setters named appropriately.

Comment: Long names are preferable unless there is an established practice IMO (int i for exsmple). In this case xPos is clear enough. xVelocity vs xVel would make sense. Very subjective of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use the class Point for (x, y).